# CMake can't find Protobuf `protobuf_generate_cpp`

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

Using

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED
    PATHS ${PROTOBUF_SEARCH_PATH}
)

if (NOT ${Protobuf_FOUND})
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Could not find Protobuf!" )
endif()    

protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS Foo.proto)
```

I am getting an error message `Unknown CMake command "protobuf_generate_cpp"`. If I check install folder of Protobuff, there is a CMake file `<istall path>/cmake/protobuf-module.cmake` which contains the function definition.

```
CMake    version: 3.10.2
Protobuf version: 3.6.1
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: It is `ProtobufConfig.cmake` file which is read during `find_package()` call. CMake stores directory, containing this file, in `Protobuf_DIR` cache variable. You may find value of this variable in `CMakeCache.txt` file, located in the build directory. Check that: 1. Proper file `ProtobufConfig.cmake` has been found (according to `Protobuf_DIR` variable). 2. Given file contains definition of `protobuf_generate_cpp` function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like the cmake API has changed a bit. Try changing it to

```
protobuf_generate(
 LANGUAGE cpp
 TARGET <YOUR_TARGET_NAME> 
 PROTOS Foo.proto)
```

This will directly add the generated files to the target's source list.
Have a look in at the `protobuf_generate` function in `protobuf-config.cmake` for the new options.

Comment: Where is the documentation for this? The official CMake documentation only lists protobuf_generate_cpp and protobuf_generate_python, even for the latest release.

Comment: I also would love to see the documentation for this. This is currently the only place on the internet that mentions this.

Comment: @scatter see my answer cmake's FindProtobuf does not provide this API. It comes from protocol buffers which is not so well documented.

Comment: @BruceAdams I don't know if the discussion on your issue is (still) true. It appears that `protobuf_generate` is now an [implementation detail(?)](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake#L141) of the CMake distributed FindProtobuf.cmake file. Looks like this was done [4 years ago](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/commit/1bcc0f3678daea6bb7f999ebded1eab471b32e28).

Comment: @jwm the point of my answer was that it could (at least in 2020) come from either cmake or protocol_buffers. Both may have changed since then. protocol buffers has definitely improved its cmake support and might be the definitive choice now. I don't know.

Comment: @BruceAdams I wasn't questioning your answer; it was very thorough. For me, learning how CMake finds things has been a perilous adventure. I was simply pointing out that the dismissive "that comes from upstream; it's not our issue" [response](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21228#note_834424) you got from CMake on your issue is not quite true. The CMake-delivered `FindProtobuf.cmake` does include (and has for a while) `protobuf_generate`.

Comment: I know it's late @scatter, but protocolbuffers finally wrote some [documentation](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/e1faf09604d26cc6803970815f91225b220175d4/docs/cmake_protobuf_generate.md) on it in September

Answer (score 8):

The existing [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56896032/1569204) helped me but miss a lot of explanation of what is going on.

[find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) can work in MODULE mode or CONFIG mode.
In MODULE mode it searches for `Find\<package\>.cmake` (typically owned by cmake).
In CONFIG mode it searches for `\<package\>Config.cmake` (provided by the package).

Both cmake and protocol buffers can provide an implementation for `protobuf_generate_cpp()`:

```
>grep -ri 'function(PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP' /opt/cmake-3.18.1/ 
/opt/cmake-3.18.1/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:function(PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP SRCS HDRS)
>grep -ri 'function(PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP' /opt/protobuf-3.5.0/
/opt/protobuf-3.5.0/lib64/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-module.cmake:function(PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP SRCS HDRS)
```

Using the PATHS hint puts cmake into CONFIG mode so that it will use the protobuf provided implementation if it can find a Config.cmake module.

In this case protobuf_generate_cpp() comes from config.cmake which requires:

```
set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE ON CACHE BOOL "")
```

Because as @HaxtraZ mentions the config module contains:

```
if(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE)
   include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/protobuf-module.cmake")
endif()
```

This is not required if using the [FindProtobuf](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/module/FindProtobuf.html) MODULE and is thus not documented there.

Though it is not really its fault cmake could warn about the possible conflict.
If have raised this here:

```
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/21228
```

I have also reported the confusion caused by the missing documentation to the protocol buffers project here:

```
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/7912
```

Note: The default on some Linux installations (at least CentOS7 and Debian9) is typically to have protocol buffers produced using configure/make rather than cmake which does not install the cmake config files at all. So find_package(protobuf 3.5.0 REQUIRED) will work but find_package(protobuf 3.5.0 REQUIRED PATH I/only/wanted/to/help) will fail.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `CONFIG` mode and setting this boolean variable does not work (on Windows at least)

Answer (score 7):

You need **`protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE`**.

I'm using CMake3.14. The last 3 lines of `protobuf-config.cmake` is:

```
if(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE)
  include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/protobuf-module.cmake")
endif()
```

and `protobuf_generate_cpp()` is defined in `protobuf-module.cmake`.

So, in order to `protobuf_generate_cpp()`, people have to turn `protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE` on in their CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE ON CACHE BOOL "")
```

Remember clean your previously generate cmake cache files then call cmake again.